# Why npm is creating a folder called '~' in my home directory?

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, archlinux, dotfiles

I have this "issue", since a couple days. I've noticed that I have a folder named '~' in my home directory and don't know how to tell npm to stop doing that. I don't even use npm that much.

This is in my home directory:

[image: home folder]

Then inside that folder (shows 0 elements because the inside folders are hidden):

[image: inside '~' folder]

And finally inside .npm-packages folder:

[image: inside .npm-packages folder]

The last one (etc) has no elements inside.

Is this a misconfiguration of npm?, How can I correct this?

Comment: You must have set a NPM related path to something using the character `~` but the piece of software using it must **not** do the tilde expansion [0]. So it is creating the directory hierarchy for you. [0] https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html

Comment: Thank you @galaux!, I realized a week ago that in my .npmrc file I had `prefix=~/.npm-packages`, so I manually changed it to `prefix=${HOME}/.npm-packages` and it seems to be fixed now. I just forgot to update this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my problem was related to the prefix path in my .npmrc file. Its content was:

`prefix=~/.npm-packages`

But according to @galaux reply:

> the piece of software using it must **not** do the tilde expansion.

So it was creating the whole directory hierarchy for me.

To solve it, I replaced `~` character to something similar: `$HOME`. So the final content in my .npmrc file is:

`prefix=$HOME/.npm-packages`

Where `$HOME` produces the output: `/home/my_user_name`.